# Como alterar conteúdo da página de acordo com o final inserido no link (URL)?

Tags: php, mysql, url

Tenho um sistema de cadastro de usuários. 
A pessoa insere algumas informações como usuario, foto, nome, uma breve apresentação pessoal, telefone, e e-mail. 
Automaticamente é gerado um id para cada um novo cadastro.
Até aí já está rodando corretamente.

Preciso que seja possível qualquer pessoa acessar algo como site.com/?p=joaozinho ou site.com/?p=123, sendo 123 o id do Joãozinho, e então a página que abrir se conectar com o banco de dados e mostrar as informações do usuário requisitado na página, como na foto a seguir:

[image: Exemplo Joãozinho]

Esse é o "código" que representaria a página do Joãozinho.

```html
<html>
 <body>
   <img src="img/joaozinho.jpg">
     <h2>Joãozinho</h2>
      <h3>Sou um cara legal!</h3>
      <h3>9999-8888</h3>
      <h3>joaozinho@hotmail.com</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jonas, você deve pegar o parâmetro da url acessando a variável `$_GET["p"]` e usar o valor na sua query de select que pegará a linha com os dados do usuário. Em seguida você imprime esses valores recuperados do banco na sua página.

Segue o código. Você deverá modificar em alguns lugares com os dados de conexão com o seu banco de dados e nome da tabela e dos campos da sua tabela pra ver funcionando. Além disso seu servidor deverá possuir a extensão PDO habilitada.

```
<?php

//CONFIG CONEXÃO com o banco de dados
// Mudar os valores abaixo pelos valores que vc usa para conectar no seu banco
$db_name = 'testdb';
$db_host= '127.0.0.1';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_password = '';  

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$db_name.';host='.$db_host;

$pdo_connection = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_password);
$pdo_connection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");


// Recupera o id do usuário pela variável passada na url
$user_id = $_GET["p"];

// Utiliza esse id como parâmetro na sua query
//Lembrar de mudar nomedasuatabela para o nome correto da sua tabela e id para nome do campo que é chave primária dessa tabela
$stmt = $pdo_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM nomedasuatabela WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($user_id));

//Recupera a linha correspondente da tabela
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($row==false)
{
    die("Não existe usuário com o id informado.");
}

// lembrar de mudar nomedocampo em cada $row['nomedocampo'] pelos nomes dos campos correspondentes que existem na sua tabela
$nome       = $row['nome'];
$descricao  = $row['descricao']; 
$telefone   = $row['telefone']; 
$email      = $row['email']; 
$urlimagem  = $row['urlimagem'];

?>

<html>
    <body>
      <img src="<?php echo $urlimagem;  ?>">
      <h2><?php echo $nome;  ?></h2>
      <h3><?php echo $descricao;  ?></h3>
      <h3><?php echo $telefone;  ?></h3>
      <h3><?php echo $email;  ?></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usei esse código e deu tudo certo, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Ah que bom!  Valew!  Se quiser dar um moral,  marque como resposta aceita e clique na setinha pra cima pra me dar pontos de reputação.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Se o problema é colocar os campos na url, tipo:

```
Http://site/usuários.asp?id=123
```

E vc quer algo como:

```
Http://site/usuário/123
```

A forma mais fácil de resolver é habilitando o URL REWRITE no seu webserver e criar uma regra. Da uma googleada q vc vai achar.

AGORA ... se vc quer algo do tipo:

```
Http://site/usuário/123/foto/1/apagar
```

O buraco é mais profundo...

Answer (score 0):

Olha pode usar da seguinte maneira:

```
www.teste.com.br?pagina=user&id=123
```

Desta maneira você coloca um `if` dentro do índex com um `$_GET` a página que quer visualizar, se for a página user, carregue ela com `include` e pegue o parâmetro id com `$_GET` novamente e puxe o id do usuário.

Uso sempre assim nas minha aplicações. Se não compreendeu como funciona te passo um exemplo completo.